# HashMap index collision while rezise

Tags: java, indexing, hashmap, collision

I am facing a problem while trying to create a HashSet. In my code I create like 43 different HashSets with 1 - 138 entries without any problem. When I try to create my 44th HashSet with 13 entries "JAVA" do something strange!

While adding the last "new" entry. HashMap.transfer(Entry[] newTable) give my "new" and also an "old" entry the same index no. After that my new entry is overwritten by the old entry. Does someone here already faced the same problem?

Well, I am using a HashSet:

```
    Set<BaseConfigSet> baseConfigSets = new HashSet<BaseConfigSet>();
        BaseConfigSet baseConfigSet = null;
...
    baseConfigSet = new BaseConfigSet(next.getBaseConfigId(), interval, next.getValue(), next.getAccountId(),
                                Section.forString(baseConfig.getSection()), baseConfig.getName(),
                                baseConfig.getDescription(), DataType.forString(baseConfig.getDataType()));

                        baseConfigSets.add(baseConfigSet);
```

BaseConfigSet is using Lombok annoations to generate some code like hashCode(), equals()... My hash contains a "baseConfigId" as int and "interval" as org.joda.time.Interval:

```
    @Getter
        @EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "baseConfigId", "interval" })
        @ToString(of={"baseConfigId", "value"})
        public static class BaseConfigSet {

            private Integer     baseConfigId;

            private Interval    interval;

            @Setter
            private String      value;

            private Integer     accountId;

            private Section     section;

            private String      sectionName;

            private String      description;

            private DataType    dataType;
...
```

Comment: code and error log plz

Comment: We really can't help you if you don't add any code.

Comment: what problem exactly? HashMaps are *expected* to keep only the last value, when you put a new value for an existing key. Unless we see the code, we cannot really understand what (and if something) is going wrong

Comment: Also, do you mean HashSet, or HashMap? Maps have entries, Sets have elements

Answer (score 2):

This sort of problem is common if you have mutated a key of a map or element of a set.  After a resize, what appeared to be two keys/elements becomes one as it is only then that the collection "realises" you modified this.

The solution is to either only use immutable key/elements or you have to take great care to ensure you don't modify a key/element after it is added.  Note: all you add to a collection is a *reference* to the object you add.  This means that if you modify an object after you added it, it will appear changed in the collection also. If you use a collection which assumes your key/elements don't change but you modify them, you will corrupt the collection.  This happens in the Maps, Sets and PriorityQueue.

Comment: actually the key doesn't need to be fully immutable, the only requirement for hash collections is idempotence of `hashCode()` and `equals()` (if key doesn't implement `Comparable`).